# ManyToOne relation: update parent on change

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

In my NestJS project I have below entities with OneToMany / ManyToOne relations:

faculty.entity.ts:

```
@OneToMany(
type => Society,
society => society.faculty,
{ eager: false })
societies: Society[];
```

society.entity.ts:

```
@ManyToOne(
type => Faculty,
faculty => faculty.societies,
{ onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
@JoinColumn()
faculty: Faculty;

@Column()
facultyId: number;
```

I want to implement a functionality to change the Faculty a Society is bound to.

So, in societies.service.ts I have patch method:

```
async patch(id: number, patchSocietyDto: PatchSocietyDto): Promise<Society> {
  const society = await this.findOne(id);

  for (const prop in patchSocietyDto) society[prop] = patchSocietyDto[prop];

  try {
    await society.save();
  } catch (err) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(err);
  }

  return society;
}
```

I would like to pass the "facultyId" property in a request body, remove existing relation and then add a new one between Faculty with id "facultyId".

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to the solution. The only thing I had to change was "eager" option set to true in One-To-Many relation:

```
@OneToMany(
  type => Society,
  society => society.faculty,
  { eager: true },
)
societies: Society[];
```

With this change, relation updates by passing a new value for "facultyId" property.